# MS ACCESS - Error runtime 3141 SQL in VBA

Tags: vba

I'm getting error in ms access while trying change subform recordsource based on combo box

```
The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.
```

here my code

```
Private Sub Text4_AfterUpdate()
If (Me.Text4.Value = "(ALL)") Then
    filterORIGIN_COD = "SELECT SUMMARY.DEST_CITY, SUMMARY.DESTINATION, Count(SUMMARY.CNOTE_NO) AS CountOfCNOTE_NO1" & _
                "FROM SUMMARY" & _
                "WHERE (((SUMMARY.ORIGIN_CODE) Like " & "'" * "'" & ")))" & _
                "GROUP BY SUMMARY.DEST_CITY, SUMMARY.DESTINATION, SUMMARY.TGL_DATA, SUMMARY.ORIGIN_CODE, SUMMARY.ORIGIN, SUMMARY.DEST_CODE;"


Else
    filterORIGIN_COD = "SELECT SUMMARY.DEST_CITY, SUMMARY.DESTINATION, Count(SUMMARY.CNOTE_NO) AS CountOfCNOTE_NO1" & _
                "FROM SUMMARY" & _
                "WHERE (((SUMMARY.ORIGIN_CODE)=" & """Me![Text4]""" & ")))" & _
                "GROUP BY SUMMARY.DEST_CITY, SUMMARY.DESTINATION, SUMMARY.TGL_DATA, SUMMARY.ORIGIN_CODE, SUMMARY.ORIGIN, SUMMARY.DEST_CODE;"

End If
Me![OUTBOUND_DETAIL].Form.RecordSource = filterORIGIN_COD
Me![OUTBOUND_DETAIL].Requery


End Sub
```

**ADDITIONAL**
actually I'm trying to filter subform (query record source), can someone show me better ways to do that? :)

Comment: The resulting strings have no space before the word "FROM", e.g., "...CountOfCNOTE_NO1FROM SUMMARY..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If trying to filter subform in a trigger event, simply use [DoCmd.ApplyFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197651.aspx) or [DoCmd.SetFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197950.aspx) *(for Access 2010+)* methods which are also available in macros:

```vb
Private Sub Text4_AfterUpdate() 
   DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[SUMMARY.ORIGIN_CODE]='" & Me![Text4] & "'"
End Sub
```